# WPF virtualization not working on windows 2008 server R2 with windows classic theme(aero disabled)

Tags: wpf, windows, windows-server-2008, ui-virtualization

I am running into a weird problem with windows server 2008 R2. I have WPF app which has virtualization enabled (virtualization stack panel and lazy loading for the tree view). It works as exepcted on windows 7 system. However on a windows 2008 R2 system with the classic wndows theme(no aero aka destop experiance turned off),  it does not. When I debug it the controls private properties indicate that virtualization is enabled, however my I see that all the data is fetched through my virtualized model.

EDIT: Enabled user experiance etc but not the windwos7 theme still the issues persists. This is on a TreeView control. I use thsi technique to enable data virtualization: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfDataVirtualization.aspx

Any ideas as to what could be going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF uses hardware acceleration to perform the rendering.  You lose functionality whenever this is not present.  Are you connecting to the server via Remote Desktop or with a direct console?

[Blog post explaining the rendering options](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/06/22/software-rendering-usage-in-wpf.aspx)

Comment: I am not using RDP or a direct console. However this is article provides some additional data to check for. Weirdly enough I develop using RDP and virtualization works just fine on Win 7 and RDP.